# Is it possible to get a closed-form expression?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have an intergral which is given as 
\begin{align}
   T= \int \limits_{0}^{\infty} \prod \limits_{n=1}^{N} 
    \left[ 1-   
    \frac{ \exp\left( - z B_n   \right) }{1 +z A_n}\right]^K \frac{\exp(-\phi z)}{\sqrt{z}} dz
\end{align}
where $A_n$, $B_n$, K, N, and $\Phi$ are positive number. 
I was wondered if it is possible to obtain a closed-form expression for the below integral.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: What is the parameter $K$?

Comment: To get someone's attention, you need to use the at symbol, followed by his name like @user64494

Comment: Hi @user64494, $K$ is a positive integer number.